# JavaScript RegExp with multiple modifiers

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to have regex with both `g` and `s` modifier?

I've tried

```
/abc/gs                         // throw error
new RegExp('abc', 'g', 's')     // s is ignored
new RegExp('abc', 'gs')         // throw error
new RegExp('abc', ['g', 's'])   // throw error
```

Comment: there is no `s` modifier in javascript regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the answer from the error thrown

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'gs'(…)

There is no `s` modifier in JavaScript regex. So it's an invalid regex that's why it's throwing error. [The available modifiers can be check on documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters).